# When reporting coefficents should I use Beta or B?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have a regression model: `news~z.narcissism+gender+age` narcissism is Z-scored, but gender and age are not. When reporting do I need to Z-score them as well? Should I report B or Beta in this case?

Comment: When you say Beta do you mean the standardised values which SPSS reports?

Comment: Yes, in my post I am using Beta to refer to the standardized value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand this (and it is SPSS jargon) Beta refers to the coefficient for one sd change in the predictor in terms of sd changes in the response. B on the other hand refers to changes in terms of your original units. So If you want to be able to see the effect of a one year change in age on your nes variable in terms of whatever units news is measured in then use B. If you want to know how many standard deviations in news are associated with a standard deviation change in age the use Beta.

I think you will have grave difficulty persuading anyone to take standard deviation changes in sex seriously.

If your report is going to be read by the vast number of people who do not use SPSS you need to be very clear what you are talking about as the rest of the world uses $\beta$ to mean something else (the unknown population value).

Comment: "I think you will have grave difficulty persuading anyone to take standard deviation changes in sex seriously." Haha!